# How much priority does scrollBy have over canvas onDraw?

Tags: android, canvas

This is a basic code for detecting touch + drawing a custom view :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { //Basic onTouch code for scrolling along the Y axis
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        mPrevious = event.getY();
    }

    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        float distance = mPrevious - event.getY();
        scrollBy(0,Math.round(distance));
        mPrevious = event.getY();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Basic drawing of a circle at (200,200)
            canvas.drawCircle(200f,200f,50f, defaultPaint);

    //canvas.setMatrix(new Matrix());

    Log.d("CANVAS", "("+canvas.getMatrix().toString()+")");

}
```

I'm working with a custom view, I'm trying to implement user scrolling functionality using `scrollBy`, but it looks like I'll have to create the logic myself.

I still want to understand how this function works. When I print log the canvas matrix in the last line, it correctly displays the new coordinates, and onDraw is called every time the touch moves.

But if I uncomment `canvas.setMatrix`, suprisingly nothing changes functionality-wise. The only difference now is that the console log shows that the canvas matrix is always equal to identity mx, even if it's correctly being scrolled. Why? How can `scrollBy` completely overwrite canvas drawing?

Comment: I don't see any difference. They both do the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure you want me to call this in the constructor, here's a video of both these functions doing exactly the same thing : https://puu.sh/BKpC6/183673ee47.webm

Comment: I also don't see where you're going with this, the main issue that I don't understand is how scrollBy overrides any modifications done in onDraw, without changing the canvas coordinates.

Comment: They still do the same thing, can you explain what's happening in this video for me? https://puu.sh/BKq1r/35b9be701f.webm

Comment: I'm seriously baffled, everything drawn before the touch event is immune from any onDraw calls, including translate, matrix change, but shapes drawn after the touch event, can correctly be translated? why?

Comment: Yes, there wasn't a difference, I don't want to waste more effort about this problem now since I implemented my own solution to scrolling without scrollBy, still interested in how it works because I tried to find its source code yesterday but I couldn't get there. So maybe someone will find an answer for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181835/discussion-between-zee-and-pskink).

Comment: Hey! Did you find the solution? I'm also having the same problem.